# How many electrons are in the d orbitals of NiCl2·6H2O?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, orbitals, transition-metals

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel%28II%29_chloride#Structure_of_NiCl2_and_its_hydrates), it says that

> $\ce{NiCl2·6H2O}$ consists of separated trans-$\ce{[NiCl2(H2O)4]}$ molecules
>   linked more weakly to adjacent water molecules. Only four of the six
>   water molecules in the formula are bound to the nickel, and the
>   remaining two are water of crystallisation.[4] Cobalt(II) chloride
>   hexahydrate has a similar structure.

So nickel chloride hexahydrate has an octahedral symmetry and the ligands are two chloride ions and 4 water molecules? Or is $\ce{NiCl2}$ a solid in water, but separates into $\ce{Ni^2+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ ions in water since they are ionic?

Does this also indicate that there are 8 electrons in the $d$ orbitals and that it will form a high-spin complex (I know that the low-spin orbitals look the same though) so that there are two unpaired electrons? I think I'm thrown off by the chloride ions because my textbook only explains complex ions like $\ce{[CoCl4]^4-}$ or $\ce{Fe(CN)6}$ which are easier to understand for me.

Comment: I think I *could* answer this, but there is a part of the question I’m not yet understanding. Second paragraph ‘or is $\ce{NiCl2}$ a solid in water, but it probably separates into $\ce{Ni^2+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ ions in water since they are ionic, right?’ <- that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The hexahydrate has octahedral symmetry, and it is very probable that this is the case for the solid and dissolved state of the complex.

The compound will not separate into the ions, because the solvation of three ions vs the solvation of one neutral complex is higher in energy, especially considering the fact that opposite charges attract. So in solution state it is a $\ce{[NiCl2(OH2)4]}$ complex with octahedral symmetry.

---

The $d$-electron count is 8, as it starts with 10 and has a formal oxidation state of II. This is always the case for $\ce{Ni^{II}}$ in any medium but vacuum.

Whether it's a high-spin or low-spin complex depends on the splitting energy of the $e_\text{g}$ and $t_\text{2g}$ molecular orbitals that arise from the $d$ orbitals in combination with the ligand group orbitals, colloquially known as $\Delta_\text{o}$ or $\Delta_\text{oct}$. Have a look at this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_field_theory) on crystal field theory for more details.

In short, there are several factors that influence the magnitude of the splitting:

- Oxidation state of central atom
- Geometry
- Ligand types

The octahedral geometry usually gives good energy splitting.$^\text{[citation needed]}$ In conjunction with a moderate oxidation state compared to Ni(0), and four mid-range splitting ligands (water), it is a safe bet to say that we will have a low-spin octahedral $d^8$ complex: Three pairs of electrons in the $t_\text{2g}$ orbitals and two unpaired electrons in the $e_\text{g}$ orbitals, that is.

Note at this point that the terms *high-spin* and *low-spin* are superfluous. The electrons in the $e_\text{g}$ orbitals will always be in a triplet configuration according to [Hund's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hund's_rule_of_maximum_multiplicity). So it will always be in a "high-spin" configuration from an experimental standpoint.

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote? I'd be glad to improve this answer.

Comment: low-spin octahedral d8 equals square planar. Or, at least, strongly distorted octahedral. Nickel has quite an interesting chemistry here, though AFAIK chloride has not strong enough field to make it low spin. Cianide, on the other hand, does. That said, nickel chloride does dissociate in water, as its solutions have measurable conductance. I suggest you to go for the sources and edit your post accordingly with references and links. I'm not posting the sources here, but they are pretty easily googleable.

Comment: @permeakra Quote from the wikipedia page: "In some derivatives, the chloride remains within the coordination sphere, whereas chloride is displaced with highly basic ligands." Water is not highly basic. Distilled water also has measurable conductance. And I don't understand at all what you mean by low-spin octahedral d8 equalling square planar... Maybe check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_field_theory#Geometries_and_crystal_field_splitting_diagrams) out for reference?

Comment: But your point is noted, I'll scour the interwebs for some information whether the chloride ligands dissociate and update my answer accordingly.

Comment: distilled water has low enough conductance to be utilized as dielectric in some applications.

Comment: As for "low-spin octahedral d8 equalling square planar"; for ligands with strong field, octahedral coordination for d8 complexes is unstable and the complex breaks down into square one. || as for "Water is not highly basic. " Even wiki states that NiCl2 solutions are acidic because of hydrolysis of Ni2+ cation. Implying that the salt does dissociate in solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34796/discussion-between-tschoppi-and-permeakra).

Comment: @Jan For reasons pointed out in the spin-off chat, I still consider only octahedral complexes. Nothing square planar going on here.

Comment: Edited the answer for more clarity in the last two paragraphs. The discussion of Jahn-Teller distortion and symmetry-breaking effects is beyond scope as I interpret it from the level of knowledge presented about the material in the question by OP.

Comment: @permeakra Here's a little (two years) newer publication than the one you cited: [DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.441322)
This is all based on EXAFS fitting, which is a highly parametrized process. And seriously, no need to get all riled up about this. Feel free to write your own answer if you don't feel that this one satisfies the requirements of this platform.